# Accessing Rails Console in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, bundler

I am using Capistrano 3 to deploy a rails app, and I have run into a problem when trying to access the rails console on my VPS.  When I run:

```
rails console production
```

I get an error that require relative can't load the file `config/boot.rb`.  The problem seems to be stemming from the fact that the app is using the rails executable in `shared/bin` whereas all of my app logic is in current/bin.  The problem is that the `shared/config` directory does not contain a `boot.rb` file. If I run:

```
bundle install --production
```

then everything seems to work.  Should I just remove `capistrano/bundler` from my cap file and have the capistrano script just run `bundle install --production`, or am I getting other benefits from `capistrano/bundler`?

Answer (score 2):

Rails console script use files in folder `bin`. So your `bin` folder must be in root folder of project (it already in your repositories), not in shared folder with symlinks.

Problem in default capistrano config `deploy.rb`:

> set :linked_dirs, %w{**bin** log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

So capistrano delete existed folders before create symlinks.

> INFO [b72e6ca9] Running /usr/bin/env rm -rf /MyProject/releases/20150409074324/bin
>
> INFO [f1ba66e7] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /MyProject/shared/bin /MyProject/releases/20150409074324/bin

Remove `bin` from `linked_dirs` will fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need the **bundle install --production** you can only write bundle install
And to the console in the production mode you can write **RAILS_ENV=production rails c**